# Embedding an Internet Explorer control - C++ WinAPI

Tags: c, internet-explorer, winapi

How can I embed an Internet Explorer control into my application using C++/WinAPI?

I swear I have searched; I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been searching for this too, some useful links:

[IWebBrowser2: how to force links to open in new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925279/iwebbrowser2-how-to-force-links-to-open-in-new-window)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1788/Loading-and-parsing-HTML-using-MSHTML-3rd-way

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3919/Using-the-WebBrowser-control-simplified

From what I remember it was most useful to implement the IHTMLDocument interface instead of the full web browser.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Try these:

- [Embed an HTML control in your own window using plain C](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3365/Embed-an-HTML-control-in-your-own-window-using-pla)
- [Programming the MSHTML Web Browser Control with C++](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/mshtml/)

Since interacting with controls such as these requires COM/COM+ programming, you could also benefit from learning those methods as well.