# C++ GUI Windows Default Browser

Tags: c++, winapi, object, user-interface, default-browser

I am trying to implement NotePad++ plugin, I am stuck in, how to get GUI of Windows Default Browser initialized with a URL in C++.

Comment: Are you actually trying to implement a browser control into Notepad++ (in some window?) or do you just want to open a web page in the default browser?

Comment: I have created a Dock in NotePad++, in Dock i want to Place Windows default browser object (and initialize it with a URL)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to implement any web browser control (i.e. utilize Internet Explorer), then you might want to have a look at [this questions and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051817/embedding-an-internet-explorer-control-c-winapi).

If you'd like to embed the user's preferred web browser, you're pretty much out of luck (there are possibly hacky ways to do it (e.g. modifying the browser's window and keeping it overlapping your control), but I wouldn't recommend them).

Comment: a lot of file missing error, i followed that question's answer. using vs2008

Comment: You might want to install the latest Windows SDK, especially when using older Express versions (didn't come with a Windows SDK preinstalled).

Answer (score 0):

Try **ShellExecute**(NULL, L"open", L"www.mywebsite.com",NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

Comment: shellexecute is to create an anchor in GUI