# Using IHTMLDocument instead of IWebBrowser2

Tags: c++, winapi, iwebbrowser2, ihtmldocument

I want to display a simple web page in my Win32 application.

I have read this question

[IWebBrowser2: how to force links to open in new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925279/iwebbrowser2-how-to-force-links-to-open-in-new-window)

I want to do exactly stated in the reply of the question, but havn't found a code example.

Is there a simple example which shows how to use IHTMLDocument instead of IWebBrowser2 to render HTML documents inside a Win32 application.

Answer (score 1):

IHTMLDocument is a non-visual component and so cannot do what you ask. IWebBrowser2 is the visual component that you need.